# Alternative to uniq -c and sort in pure awk

Tags: macos, bash, sorting, awk, uniq

Here is one command used to filter out from the access.log file the number of hits by IP address and then count the number of hits for each IP and sort them from the lowest to the highest count:

```
awk '{print $1}' "${ACCESSLOG}" | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nk1
```

and here an excerpt from the result:

```
 26 45.59.193.115
 26 74.125.63.33
 27 88.156.36.194
 28 12.208.4.156
 29 12.208.4.156
 31 98.236.117.199
 32 176.9.82.6
 33 187.34.167.111
 35 67.110.83.252
 37 54.184.4.183
 39 195.59.2.173
 39 70.199.109.118
 44 12.208.4.156
 59 88.156.36.194
```

Now is it possible to get to the same result with the only use of awk? 
No uniq -c, no sort.

Can't seem to find much info on the web about this...

Comment: What is that final `uniq` getting you?

Comment: I think OS X/bsd awk means you get to do the sorting in awk manually or use `sort` on the awk-unique-ified output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory - yes, you can. But there are two parts here:

Can you implement sort and uniq? Sort will be quite tricky, but sure, you can implement anything in awk. Uniq should be trivial.

Can you implement your pipeline, so exactly `| uniq -c | sort -nk1 | uniq`. Yes, and it's not going to be very hard. Just use something like:

```
awk '{ips[$1]++} END {for (ip in ips) { print ips[ip], ip}}'
```

That does the counting / uniq part. You'll have to add `asort` to sort the entries at the end.

Comment: You don't need `if` to get the numbers to count correctly. Non-existent awk values default to `0` so you can just `++` on the entry in the `ips` array and your count works out.

Comment: Thanks @EtanReisner, that's useful!

Comment: asort is implemented with gawk, not awk.

Answer (score 1):

GNU awk has a feature that makes counting and sorting easy:

```
awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"} { a[$1]++ } END{for (ip in a)print a[ip],ip}' access.log
```

The statement `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"` causes the array to be ordered according to value, as opposed to key, in ascending numerical order.

(The default awk on Mac OSX is BSD so don't try this there.)

#### Example

Suppose that we have the input file:

```
$ cat access.log
74.125.63.33
45.59.193.115
45.59.193.115
74.125.63.33
74.125.63.33
74.125.63.33
195.59.2.173
```

Then the above produces:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"} { a[$1]++ } END{for (ip in a)print a[ip],ip}' access.log
1 195.59.2.173
2 45.59.193.115
4 74.125.63.33
```

Comment: @JeanmichelCote, you can install gawk on your system. Unfortunately things like FPAT only work with gawk.

Comment: So I got to my linux server to try and actually your command is working fine but is a bit slower than @viraptor's awk one.
real 0m0.014s - user 0m0.000s - sys 0m0.008s against real 0m0.008s - user 0m0.004s - sys 0m0.008s

Answer (score 1):

@viraptor Actually, i corrected my command because both our results were different and it now looks more like this:

`awk '{print $1}' "${ACCESSLOG}" | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nk1`

real    0m0.020s

user    0m0.016s

sys 0m0.012s

So I added the sort command to your initial proposition because I can't use neither gawk (asort) nor GNU:

`awk '{if(ips[$1]) {ips[$1]++} else {ips[$1]=1}} END {for (ip in ips) { print ips[ip], ip}}' "$ACCESSLOG" | sort -nk1`

real    0m0.019s

user    0m0.004s

sys 0m0.008s

Whereas your refactored command :

`awk '{ips[$1]++} END {for (ip in ips) { print ips[ip], ip}}' "${ACCESSLOG}" | sort -nk1`

real    0m0.014s

user    0m0.004s

sys 0m0.012s

Interesting to compare speeds...